# How to merge 2 android projects

Tags: android, eclipse, merge

HI I have and android project A, I have been working on it, and also a friend of mine has been  working on it, so now I have 2 projects A-Mine and A-Friend (I have nor svn, cvs nor git). Is there a way to get a diff of or to merge them, using ecplise or tortoise or anything (windows based)

Thnak u very much
 best regards 
 Ignacio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought my friends there is always another way, Turns out ecplise won't allow you to open twice same project in the same workspace, but you can very well match up files and folders with simple windows copy + paste, so what is what you do? Yo open one project in eclipse and paste the renamed folders of the second project. the you can use Eclipses Compare With tool, to match up all files in a certain directory.

Clean, easy and fast

Answer (score 0):

Now's a great chance to set up source control! Commit your version into source control, have your friend check it out, create a new branch and recursively copy all his files into it. Then just use the tools provided by your source control software of choice to merge those changes into the main branch. Done!

Comment: not gonna work I have both projects in my pc and I have to fix it tonight, any ideas?

Comment: this can be implemented in a night easily. Your alternative solutions is to do it by hand. You choose.